# JavaScript fixed method for decimal places

Tags: javascript

I do not know what is wrong with my code.

> Use `toFixed()` method to display a numeric value with a specified number of decimal places.  Display salary as currency with 2 decimal places

```js
var payRate=7.675;
var hours=25;
var total=payRate*hours;

console.log('You have earned $' + total);
console.log('You have earned $' + total.toFixed(2) + '.');
```

`console.log()` says `undefined`?

Comment: `console.log() says undefined?` Not here.  Which browser?

Comment: Ignoring everything but `JavaScript` and `Output`, I'm guessing [this is probably what you're seeing](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean#h=vIE9oIEAJYEBvIE9oIECJYEDvIE9oIEETKCBAI0ggQKmU9CAoDgggEBMo4EFiyCBBCZT0ICgOCCAQEzMo4EFi1PQgKCBBCCAqiU7iyOBBvDh+dLh9GW3rra3Nejv9fJzsjX07/ThbNnv9aDo4fbloOXh8u7l5KAkLg==&i=&f=0&w=1).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I followed your suggestion and ran the code in another browser and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined` is not the return value of your code, its the return value of `console.log()`

Since `console.log()` returns nothing it prints `undefined`

Above `undefined` you will have your value, Please run your code again, I m pasting the same code

```js
var payRate=7.675;
var hours=25;
var total=payRate*hours;

console.log('You have earned $' + total);
console.log('You have earned $' + total.toFixed(2) + '.');
```

**Please run the code snippet and check console**

Comment: Good job reading between the lines.  This has thrown me for a loop in the past.  If someone is copying/pasting directly into terminal, the output of the previous command is echo'd.  With `console.log`, the output is `undefined`.  It's a false-positive error.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ran your code snippet and this time it did print the answers above undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine,its print look like-

```
You have earned $191.875
You have earned $191.88.
```

PS: You can check your browser version.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ran the code again and did get the answers above undefined.